# makefile: Selective suppressing echoing in multiple line rules

Tags: makefile

I know that a line in a rule may be suppressed using prefix @. So it works:

```
test: 
    @echo Hallo1
    @echo Hallo2
```

Results in

```
Hallo1
Hallo2
```

But I want to selectively suppress some lines and some not. E.g.

```
test: 
    echo Hallo1
    @echo Hallo2
```

Results in

```
echo Hallo1
echo Hallo2
Hallo1
Hallo2
```

So I see that if echoing is not suppressed in the first line of the rule I have no chance to reenable suppressing later. Anyone knows why and how to achieve this?

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. I cannot reproduce that, not even with the old GNU make 3.81. What version of make do you use?

Comment: Hey and thanks to be my first commenter ;-)
I use
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-msys
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

on a MSYS environment on WINDOWS. Perhaps this is a problem of my environment. I'll check it on my LINUX system. Moment...

Comment: Oh, on a LINUX environment there is no problem about this. So I think my MSYS environment is "special".

Comment: Honestly, I cannot imagine a reason why GNU make 4.3, even on MSYS, would behave like this. Each tab-indented line is a different recipe and make honors the `@` silencer for each of them. Are you 100% sure that what you tried is really what you show? Did you check twice?

Comment: Yes, I checked even more than twice. I try to achieve wanted behavior for a long time. I use a long makefile for a complex project where this question arises often. E.g. running the linker and afterwards copying resulting files. Always the first line determines what happens later. I also tried another make executable gnumake.exe with the same behavior. Then I tried to call make once from a bash and once from a cmd environment. Always the same behavior.

Comment: By the way, don't you have the `.ONESHELL:` special target somewhere in your Makefile?

Comment: Thanks Renaud,
that is it. I introduced ONESHELL long ago, so I didn't think about this.

Comment: You're welcome. This is why you should **always** test the exact MCVE you post, not something else and assume it will behave the same. In this case it would have been better to test your 3 lines Makefile alone. You would probably not even have posted your question.

Comment: You are right, lesson learned ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I used the .ONESHELL: directive in my makefile which of course explains the behavior. I added my test target at the end of my long makefile, therefore I didn't check it. Sorry and thanks...